# How to combine two vars in android listview: first left-justified and second right-justified

Tags: android, listview

I am using standard ListView and Adapter as
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, itemList).

The list structure as follows:
LOOOOOOOOOOOONG ITEM NAME 1

SHORT ITEM NAME 2

I need to add quantity to the text1 line. I can concatenate it with ITEM NAME,so it looks like

LOOOOOOOOOOOONG ITEM NAME1 845

SHORT ITEM NAME2 132

How to push quantity to the right, so all of them will be aligned and right justified? Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a custom Adapter that inflate a custom composite View for each cell.

In a new CustomAdapter.java (Item is your data POJO: see below)

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private final Context mContext;
    private final List<Item> mItemList;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<Item> itemList) {
        mContext = context;
        mItemList = itemList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mItemList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Item getItem(int position) {
        return mItemList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        CustomViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.custom_cell, parent, false);
            CustomViewHolder holder = new CustomViewHolder();
            holder.itemNameTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview_item_name);
            holder.itemQuantityTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview_item_quantity);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (CustomViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        Item item = getItem(position);
        holder.itemNameTextView.setText(item.getName());
        holder.itemQuantityTextView.setText(item.getQuantity());
        return convertView;
    }

    private static class CustomViewHolder {
        public TextView itemNameTextView;
        public TextView itemQuantityTextView;
    }
}
```

with custom_cell.xml being :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_item_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textview_item_quantity"
        android:singleLine="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_item_quantity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the Item POJO :

```
public class Item {
    private final String mName;
    private final String mQuantity;

    public Item(String itemName, String itemQuantity) {
        mName = itemName;
        mQuantity = itemQuantity;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public String getQuantity() {
        return mQuantity;
    }
}
```

Use it with your ListView by doing :

```
listView.setAdapater(new CustomAdapter(this, itemList));
```

Comment: I am trying to implement this, thanks. I am having two problems: 1.Error:(13, 8) error: CustomAdapter is not abstract and does not override abstract method getItemId(int) in Adapter and 2. Error:(43, 40) error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to CustomViewHolder (for holder=convertView.getTag()). Any suggestions?

Comment: I wrote the code without IDE, sorry for the mistakes. You have to implements a dummy getItemId() method for the first error and you have to explicitly cast the tag to CustomViewHolder for the second one. See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks! Works exactly as I need!

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, itemList)
```

Create a new custom xml file in res/layout [say called `your_layout_name.xml`] and replace the `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` in the code above with "R.layout.your_layout_name". In that file, put in the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall" />
```

### Explanation

[Here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_1.xml) is the original `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` layout which, in that ArrayAdapter code, defines the layout of the row:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall" />
```

All that needed to be changed was the "gravity" parameter. That defines the alignment of the text, and all you needed to add was "right" to it.

Note: The gravity parameter normally aligns all of its contents in any View. Say, for a LinearLayout, this would try to align all of its child elements. For a TextView, it aligns its text.

Comment: Sorry, this does not work for me. All it did it made whole string "ITEM NAME 825" right-justified. What I need is to make "ITEM NAME" left-justified and "825" right-justified. Sorry if I was not clear.